# In SSIS how to check target load proper data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

New in SSIS , don't know how to check target table load data is valid.

Table structure is bellow 
[image]

Bellow SSIS package load target table FactProductInventory from DimProductInventory table.

[image]

DimProduct and DimDate have huge data , so need one process to check my target table load valid data via SSIS pacakge.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into SSIS that does this automatically.  You will need to write SQL Queries that check the data and handle the results of those queries with custom code.

Comment: thanks for your information, will you please provide some guideline how to handle sql queries that check the data.

Comment: You would use the queries to populate variables and then use either script tasks or precedence constraints to do what you want based on the values of the variables.